# Can I freely combine the present perfect simple tense with the present perfect progressive tense within the same sentence or is it bad grammar?

Tags: sentence-construction, present-tense, sentence-choice

> 1. Jim talks to Fran on Finn's phone while Finn and Gina watch him.
> 2. Jim talks to Fran on Finn's phone while Finn and Gina are watching him.
> 3. Jim is talking to Fran on Finn's phone while Finn and Gina watch him.
> 4. Jim is talking to Fran on Finn's phone while Finn and Gina are watching him.

Can I freely combine the present perfect simple tense with the present perfect progressive tense or is it bad grammar?

Which one of the sentences would be the normal choice?

Answer (score 1):

It's suboptimal grammar, but it's acceptable.

I wouldn't bat an eye reading any of these, but if I were editing your paper, I'd match the tenses.